# Как вызвать функцию javascript в функции PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

На wordpress сайте я хочу в functions.php написать функию с условием, чтобы если условие верно - вызывалась функция javascript. Такое можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (uslovie) {
  echo "<script>myFunction();</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если кратко, то можно передавать с сервера(с помощью `ajax`) тело функции и вызывать `new Function([args], body)`, где `args` - аргументы, `body` - тело функции.

Answer (score 0):

PHP отдает в броузер HTML; а HTML может содержать `<script> f() </script>`, например.